# Alternative to creating "connection" between elements in .xib and swift classes via drag & drop

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, swift, ios8

I am currently trying to learn the creation of views with the interface builder and the new swift language.

I want to create a custom Table Cell. 
After "designing" it in the interface builder I attached a class to it. The cell has 3 labels.  The next step would be "connect" the labels to the code. I am used to do this by creating an IBOutlet by ctrl-dragging the elements in the interfacebuilder to the code.

However due to xcode beta fun this makes xcode crash - every single time. Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: which beta version are you using. It used to crash when I was using beta 1 but not on beta 3.